# Clear cell output in iPython Jupyter notebook executed in VS Code using Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to clear the cell output during runtime in an Jupyter notebook executed in VS Code using the new Python extension (which supports running Jupyter notebooks in VS Code)?

Ususally I use [IPython.display.clear_output()](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output) to acomplish that when executing Jupyter notebooks in a web browser, for instance to get a progress bar for long data imports, something along those lines. VS Code for some reason seems to ignore this, which results in a VERY long cell output potentially crashing the kernel during runtime.

Edit (a small example):

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown, HTML, clear_output
from time import sleep

def progress(cur, tot):
    clear_output(True)
    display(
       HTML(
        '''
            <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px;">
                <div style="font-weight:bold;">Dataset:</div>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px; text-align:left;">
                <div>{:d} / {:d}</div>
            </div>
        '''.format(cur, tot)
        ),
        HTML('<progress value=\"{:d}\" max=\"{:d}\" style=\"width:100%; height:1.5em;\"></progress>'.format(cur, tot))
    )

for i in range(10):
    progress(i, 10)
    sleep(0.2)

clear_output()
display(Markdown('Done!'))
```

Comment: Hey Breit. I'm a developer on this extension and I don't believe that we've tested out that method of clearing the output. The best way to get this fixed would be to file an issue on our github here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Comment: Thanks Ian, I filed the issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7970